# LARAVEL Delete method does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have strange problem and I don't see the solution. Please help me :D

So I wrote the artisan command: `user:seek-and-destroy`, where I want to destroy user and his relations.

Somewhere in command code:

```
        $paymentBinding = $user->payment_binding(); //HasMany relation

        if ($paymentBinding->count() > 0) {

            print_r($paymentBinding->get()->toArray());

            $paymentBinding->delete();
            //Methods like destroy(), DB::delete(), delete by id, also don't work

            print_r($paymentBinding->get()->toArray());

        }
```

Response in console:

```
root@47a114f8ea98:/var/www/app# php artisan user:seek-and-destroy //Execute the comand

//First print_r()
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 475
            [reference] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [identifier] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [created_at] => 2018-06-26 14:56:10
            [updated_at] => 2018-06-26 14:56:10
            [id] => xxxx
        )

)
//Second print_r()
Array
(
)
```

Command response looks like it's working but it isn't :c The record has remained in the database

query.log:

```
delete from `users_payment_binding` where `user_id` = ? [475]
```

Everything looks good, but if I execute the command one more time, I have the same response, because `delete()` method didn't remove the record from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain some minor details here,

```
$user->payment_binding(); // it will return a query builder instance
$user->payment_binding; // it will return payment_binding object
```

So, try to delete it like this

```
$user->payment_binding()->delete();
```

Comment: don't work :c It's looks like my laravel use 'cache' db ? I really don't know what the * is happen.

Comment: query is sending properly, but its not working, no reaction in db ;c

Comment: then there must be some other problem. If you are using transactions then make sure that you are also committing it.

Comment: Man ... I love you :D How did you know that I use the transaction :D That was the problem ! Thank you very very much :D